# Redirect to https except one link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I use this code for redirect all link to `https` and `www`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myname.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But i want one link not redirect to `https`

> Example :

```
http://myname.com --> https://www.myname.com
http://myname.com/file.php -- > https://www.myanem.com/file.php
http://myname.com/except.php -- > http://www.myanem.com/except.php
```

In top example , i want `except.php` **not** redirect to `https`

Comment: Note that if you don't redirect all link to https for browsers, you can't use HSTS, the only protection against MitM and SSLstrip.

Comment: @Mohammad What about the `https://myname.com/except.php`, do you want it to stay `https` or rewrite back to `http`?

Comment: @DusanBajic, i want back to http

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/except\.php$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/except\.php$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Error not loading page, and reloading this to https, again reload ro http for ever